# Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t boot into a usable system after updates. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-after-updates-what-should-i-do)

I am trying to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. I followed ubuntu's instructions on the website and I'm still stuck. Should I just manually do the upgrade instead?

Comment: YES. you should. IMHO always better to do a fresh install than "upgrade"

Comment: Can you edit your question to show exactly what error messages you are getting? [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69531/how-do-i-recover-from-this-broken-upgrade) might help you.

Comment: I agree with @HamishDowner we need to know more about what is stuck before we can help or direct you to a duplicate question.